# DirectX9 C++ - Load texture while window minimized

Tags: c++, directx

Short question, is it possible to load in DirectX9 while my window is minimized?

When I try to do so my D3DXCreateTextureFromFile always return D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE. Otherwise everything works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under DirectX 9 rules, it is not possible. When the device has lost focus, everything is stale. When you get the focus back, you have to destroy everything before you can even reset it, then recreate everything again. It would not make sense to let the application create new resources that you will have to destroy before they can be used.

Comment: Funny thing is that I call LostDevice and ResetDevice for my lines, sprites and fonts, but not for textures. They work just fine after device reset.

Comment: If you look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174714(v=vs.85).aspx it is state black on white, everything created in the pool default have to be destroy prior to Reset. Is it possible that you use a DX9Ex device instead that is closer to DX11 for focus lost. DX9 is quite old and they may have lower the restriction in recent OS for simplicity in the drivers even for DX9.